# Dynamically change tab icons' color with PageChangeListener

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, tint

I want to change the tab icons' color like Facebook app.

When `ViewPager` 's state is `SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING`, then change all icons' color to unselected (gray) color, on the other hand, when `ViewPager` 's state is `SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING` and `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE`, then change the selected tab's icon to selected (white) color.

I did a test: scroll the currently selected fragment to the other fragments but still keeps the `SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING` state.

Here is a strange situation, I ran the app on the emulator and it seems to work perfectly, but when I ran the app on real device, it didn't change the selected tab's color to white when the `ViewPager` state is `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE` or `SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING`.

I added a `addOnPageChangeListener` to `ViewPager`, and changed colors in different states.

Any tips?

Here is my code:

```
void setupViews() {
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        colorSelected = ContextCompat.getColor(ctx, R.color.itemSelected);//white
        colorUnselected = ContextCompat.getColor(ctx, R.color.itemUnselected);//gray

        pagerIcons = new Drawable[2];
        pagerIcons[0] = DrawableCompat.wrap(VectorDrawableCompat.create(ctx.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_list_black_24dp, null));
        pagerIcons[1] = DrawableCompat.wrap(VectorDrawableCompat.create(ctx.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp, null));

        ViewPagerHelper.TabOption option = new ViewPagerHelper.TabOption(true, true);
        helper = new ViewPagerHelper(getSupportFragmentManager(), mViewPager, tabLayout, option);
        helper.bindViewPager();

        helper.addFragmentWithTabIcon(new ExpenseIncomeFragment(), pagerIcons[0], ExpenseIncomeFragment.TAG);
        helper.addFragmentWithTabIcon(new FragmentWishList(), pagerIcons[1], FragmentWishList.TAG);

        mViewPager.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                //if (positionOffset>0)DrawableCompat.setTint(pagerIcons[mViewPager.getCurrentItem()], colorUnselected);
                Log.e("MainActivity","position="+position+" 
positionOffset="+positionOffset+" positionOffsetPixels="+positionOffsetPixels);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                Log.e("MainActivity","position="+position);

pagerIcons[mViewPager.getCurrentItem()].setColorFilter(colorSelected, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                int pos = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
                switch (state) {
                    case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
                        Log.e("MainActivity","SCROLL_STATE_IDLE" + " getCurrentItem="+pos);

                        pagerIcons[pos].setColorFilter(colorSelected, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                        break;
                    case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING:
                        Log.e("MainActivity","SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING" + " getCurrentItem="+pos);
                        pagerIcons[pos].setColorFilter(colorUnselected, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                        break;
                    case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING:
                        Log.e("MainActivity","SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING" + " getCurrentItem="+pos);
                        pagerIcons[pos].setColorFilter(colorSelected, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                        break;
                }

            }
        });
        helper.update();

        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        int len = pagerIcons.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            pagerIcons[i].setColorFilter(colorUnselected,
            PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }
        pagerIcons[0].setColorFilter(colorSelected,PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

    });
}
```

The class `ViewPagerHelper` is used to bind `ViewPager` to `TabLayout`.
`pagerIcons` are drawables for tab icons, I tint the color to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're working with vector drawables, you can solve this problem in a different way. You can get rid of the whole `OnPageChangeListener` and leave yourself with just this:

```
void setupViews() {
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

    pagerIcons = new Drawable[2];
    pagerIcons[0] = VectorDrawableCompat.create(ctx.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_list_black_24dp, null);
    pagerIcons[1] = VectorDrawableCompat.create(ctx.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp, null);

    ViewPagerHelper.TabOption option = new ViewPagerHelper.TabOption(true, true);
    helper = new ViewPagerHelper(getSupportFragmentManager(), mViewPager, tabLayout, option);
    helper.bindViewPager();

    helper.addFragmentWithTabIcon(new ExpenseIncomeFragment(), pagerIcons[0], ExpenseIncomeFragment.TAG);
    helper.addFragmentWithTabIcon(new FragmentWishList(), pagerIcons[1], FragmentWishList.TAG);

    mViewPager.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
    helper.update();

    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
}
```

Instead of trying to manage the color of the icons in Java, you can let the system do it for you by managing them in the `<vector>` drawables themselves. First, create a color selector file in your `res/color/` directory:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/itemSelected" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/itemUnselected"/>
</selector>
```

Then use this color in your vector files:

```
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/my_color_selector"
        android:pathData="M3,13h2v-2L3,11v2zM3,17h2v-2L3,15v2zM3,9h2L5,7L3,7v2zM7,13h14v-2L7,11v2zM7,17h14v-2L7,15v2zM7,7v2h14L21,7L7,7z"/>
</vector>
```

If you need to support API levels below 21, you can't use color selectors directly in your vectors. Instead, create two copies of each vector drawable, one with the selected color and one with the unselected color. Then build a `StateListDrawable` in Java and assign that to your `pagerIcons` array:

```
Drawable selected0 = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_list_black_24dp_selected);
Drawable unselected0 = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_list_black_24dp_unselected);

StateListDrawable statelist0 = new StateListDrawable();
statelist0.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_selected}, selected0);
statelist0.addState(StateSet.WILD_CARD, unselected0);

pagerIcons[0] = statelist0;
```

Regardless of whether you can use a color selector in XML or have to build the StateListDrawable in Java, the root concept is the same: let the Android framework decide which tab is selected, and let it take care of colorizing for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used the color selector xml to directly put into my vector drawables xml in the first time. But in my case, I still need those vector drawables for other use, i.e., FloatActionButton's icon, so the drawables must be duplicated (delete the selector section code) if I use the above solution. Or, do you have any idea about it? By the way, thanks for the solution again. I upped this answer. :)

Comment: Personally, I would simply duplicate the vector drawable files and use different colors. In general, I only re-use resources in multiple places when the contents are _logically_ identical. In other words, do your tabs and your FAB use the same icon by coincidence, or will they always use the same icon (if you changed one you would always change the other)? Even then, duplicating the xml to change the color isn’t entirely unreasonable. The only other option is to tint one of them programmatically in Java.